# Replace All Backslashes on a Property File

Tags: java, android, file-io, properties

I was looking at a `Properties` file I'm testing and I realized that every time I do a `Properties.store()` values that contain characters like `:` and `/` receive a backslash, but I want my property file to be read by other programs that are not written in Java (so they will not use the `Properties` library) and those backslashes are causing problems on them. Is there any way to save the file without those?

---

I've tried building this function, which is called after the `Properties` file has been saved:

```
private void replaceInFile(File file) throws IOException {
    File tmpFile = new File("/sdcard/test.prop");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
    Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while (br.ready()) {
        fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("\\", "") + "\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

But I'm getting this error when the function is called:

> 02-03 13:05:34.757: E/AndroidRuntime(15558): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE near index 1:
>    \
>     ^

Comment: Could you use storeToXML() instead, it may get round the problem.

Answer (score 6):

These are special characters. They must be escaped with a slash.

`=` and `:` are symbols that separate key from value. What if you have `foo=bar=baz`? Or `foo:bar:baz`? Which is the key and which is the value

If you want to enforce different rules, then implement your own mechanism and don't use `java.util.Properties`. For the complete set of rules see [`Properties.load(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)

You can, after storing the properties, 1. read to string 2. replace escaped characters. 3. write the new string to file.